# LaTeX - mdframed shadow color/opacity

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, mdframed, transparency, shadows

I currently have a problem with the [`mdframed`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) shadow color. If I set the `shadowcolor` parameter to `black`, the shadow will actually be grey (I guess because it is not fully opaque...), as seen on the [picture](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/09/1456941609-capture-d-ecran-2016-03-02-a-18-56-41.png).

How can I make a fully black (or any color) shadow with the `mdframed`?

Here is the code I used:

```
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=white, shadow=true, shadowcolor=black, linewidth=1pt, linecolor=red, shadowsize=5.5pt]
text

\end{mdframed}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `TiKZ` shadows use `opacity=.5` and `mdframed` uses default settings. The problem is that `mdframed` doesn't offer any option to change anything from shadows except their color, so we must go to `TiKZ` to change `opacity`, something like `\tikzset{every shadow/.style={opacity=1}}` seems to work, but it will change opacity for all `mdframed` boxes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{every shadow/.style={opacity=1}}

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=white, shadow=true, shadowcolor=black, 
          linewidth=1pt, linecolor=red, shadowsize=5.5pt]
text

\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

An alternative solution could be to change from `mdframed` to [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) which offers easily customizable shadows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}   

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[notitle, sharp corners, colframe=red, colback=white, 
       boxrule=1pt, boxsep=0pt, enhanced, 
       shadow={3pt}{-3pt}{0pt}{opacity=1,black}]
text
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]